# "Link" link on review page - unexpected behavior

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, review, permalink

I discovered this over on gamedev.stackexchange, but I've reproduced it on Stackoverlow and here on meta.

When reviewing a question in the /review page, clicking on the "link" link should provide a a small popup with a link that can be copied and shared. Instead, it navigates to the actual question post.

[image]

Specifically, it acts more like "link" in the reputation standings pages than "link" on the question pages. If this is by design I think it should be the other way around, since the title of the question acts as a link to the question, and everywhere else it says "link" under a question like this it provides a link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fixed in latest... was fairly tricky to sort out.